# iOS - How To Provide My App's Download Link In Text Message

Tags: ios

I'm trying to implement functionality in my app where the user can invite his phone contact to the app via text message. I need to put the app store download link url in the text message as well.

I haven't submitted my app yet, so where can I find the download link? How do I know what it is if I haven't even submitted to the App Store yet?